# Defining a topology on $\mathbf{Q}$

Tags: general-topology, terminology, definition

> We may define a topology on the set $\mathbf{Q}$ of rational numbers
> by taking for opens sets all unions of bounded open intervals.

I am not sure I understand this. Do they mean that we take
$$\mathfrak{D}:=\left\{A\ \middle|\ (\exists x)(\exists y)\left(x\in\mathbf{Q}^{\mathbf{N}}\land y\in\mathbf{Q}^{\mathbf{N}}\land A=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbf{N}}\,]x_n,y_n[\right)\right\}$$
for the open sets of this topology?

Comment: You are close, but not correct: the union is taken over arbitrary families of open intervals, not just for countable families.

Comment: @HanulJeon Thank you for your help. So, replacing $\mathbf{N}$ by an arbitrary set and existentially quantifying over this set will fix it, correct? I.e. replacing the formula in the set-builder definition by the formula $(\exists I)(\exists x)(\exists y)\left(x\in\mathbf{Q}^I\land y\in\mathbf{Q}^I\land A=\bigcup_{i\in I}\ ]x_i,y_i[\right)$.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: (Note, however, your countable version is still a basis of your space, although it is not a topology.)

Comment: @HanulJeon. Will it make any practical difference whether one takes countable or arbitrary unions here? Can you give an example of an open set that is uncountable union, but not a countable union, of open intervals?

Comment: @md2perpe Good point, I think you are right that they are the same (but it needs some proof.)

Comment: @HanulJeon. I guess that it's [second countable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-countable_space), just as is $\mathbb R$ with its standard topology.

Comment: Note that there *are* only countably many open intervals with rational endpoints, so this union is always at most countable a priori.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reasonable interpretations of *bounded open interval in* $\Bbb Q$, but they yield the same topology. If by *interval* they mean *order-convex set*, then the set of intervals in question is

$$\mathscr{B}=\{(x,y)\cap\Bbb Q:x,y\in\Bbb R\text{ and }x<y\}\;;$$

if they also want the endpoints of the intervals to be rational, it’s

$$\mathscr{B}=\{(x,y)\cap\Bbb Q:x,y\in\Bbb Q\text{ and }x<y\}\;.$$

In either case the topology that they’re defining is

$$\tau=\left\{\bigcup\mathscr{U}:\mathscr{U}\subseteq\mathscr{B}\right\}\;,$$

the set of unions of arbitrary subcollections of $\mathscr{B}$.

Comment: Sorry to bother you: would you please clarify the following for me? Why is $\tau$ closed under union? Suppose we have a family $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ of elements of $\tau$. Then for each $i\in I$ there exists $\mathscr{U}_i\subset\mathscr{B}$ such that $X_i=\bigcup\mathscr{U}_i$. Now, why is $\bigcup_{i\in I}\left(\bigcup\mathscr{U}_i\right)\in\tau$? I.e., why is $\bigcup\mathscr{U}_i\subset\mathscr{B}$?

Comment: @alf262: $\bigcup\mathscr{U}_i$ generally **isn’t** a subset of $\mathscr{B}$. But every member of each $\mathscr{U}_i$ is a member of $\mathscr{B}$, so every member of $\bigcup_{i\in I}\bigcup\mathscr{U}_i$ is a member of $\mathscr{B}$, and $\bigcup_{i\in I}\bigcup\mathscr{U}_i$ is therefore the union of members of $\mathscr{B}$ and thus in $\tau$. More generally, if $\mathscr{A}$ is any family of sets, the collection $\left\{\bigcup\mathscr{S}:\mathscr{S}\subseteq\mathscr{A}\right\}$ is closed under arbitrary unions: the union of a bunch of unions of members of $\mathscr{A}$ is the union ...

Comment: ... of all the members of $\mathscr{A}$ that went into those unions.

Comment: Great, thank you.

Comment: @alf262: You’re welcome.